# ToolbarItem getting highlighted when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

It seems like by default the `ToolbarItem` is getting highlighted anytime anything is scrolled behind it e.g `List`. Is there a way to disable the highlight? For example the application Signal uses that technique where the `ToolbarItem` is same without changes, nice and has thin material effect. Or are they using a custom toolbar and this cannot be changed since it seems system default.

Here is non-highlighted before scrolling list items:
[image]

And here it gets highlighted when scrolling:
[image]

```
.navigationBarTitle("Element", displayMode: .inline)
.toolbar {
                       
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        Menu {
            Button(action: { selectedFilter = .all }) {
                Label("Show All", systemImage: "line.3.horizontal")
            }
```

Comment: Set its accent color.

Comment: I tried `.accentColor()`,  but did not seem to do anything? @ElTomato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put this `init` into your View

```
init() {
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = .clear // in your case, you can set it as black color for dark mode
    appearance.shadowColor = .clear // to remove thin line just under the NavigationBar
    
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```

**standardAppearance:** The appearance settings for a standard-height navigation bar.
**compactAppearance:** The appearance settings for a compact-height navigation bar.
**scrollEdgeAppearance:** The appearance settings for the navigation bar when the edge of scrollable content aligns with the edge of the navigation bar.

Link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/3198028-standardappearance

Comment: Thank you, that was what I needed. My last question would be is it possible to apply it to a specific tab view? For example I have 2 views with a button switch and would like to have it only where my list view is

Comment: If you put the same code from the init() inside a button or a function, then yes, it would be possible. However, it should be called before the other view is shown. If not, you have to force the view to refresh for redrawing.